# Receving http network response code in app

Tags: android

I want to get the network response code of server in webview/BrowserFrame/WebViewClient.
Eailer it was working fine until 2.3 but from 3.0 /4.0 WebViewClient API(onReciveError) is not working and No http resource response is available in app.

I there any other alternative to recive it whenever I pass a url to webview.

Comment: ThreadPolicy has been changed since 3.0, you can not perform network action on UI thread anymore.

Comment: @yorkw can you give a class name which can explain the change in ThreadPolicy...I  mean , I want to know the what is the change in ThreadPolicy so that I can change my requirement accoundly..

Comment: Check out my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8706464/defaulthttpclient-to-androidhttpclient/8706961#8706961) too see if it helps you out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access the http response headers in a WebView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134389/access-the-http-response-headers-in-a-webview)