# HTTP POST request ANDROID 4 (working in 2.3)?

Tags: android, http-post, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, http-request

Ok so, here is the deal, I've coded an app that requests via HTTP (post) data from a web url, the data is returned using JSon arrays and i parse those arrays to get what i want.

Up until there there's no problem using android 2.3.x but when i test it in Android 4 it just does not work at all.

Here is my code:

```
public boolean testConexio(){

    boolean status = false;

    String rutaServer = "URL.php";
    //Log.e("log_tag", "Ruta server: "+rutaServer);
    InputStream is = null;
    String result = "";
    String temporal;

    //Valors a demanar/enviar
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param1",config.getUserDB())); // parametros POST!
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param2",config.getPassDB())); // parametros POST!

    //http post
    try{
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(rutaServer);
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs,"UTF-8")); // valors POST UTF 8 coded <-- I KNOW! this is the way i need them spanishfag here
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
    }

    //Convierte la respuesta a String
    try{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF-8"),8); // again, spanishfag here
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result=sb.toString();
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
    }

    //Parse la respuesta JSon
    try{
        JSONObject jArray = new JSONObject(result);
        temporal = jArray.getString("status");
        if(temporal.equals("true")){
            status = true;
        }
        Log.i("log_tag","Status: "+jArray.getString("status"));
    }catch(JSONException e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
    }

    return status;
}
```

Can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong? or what i need to change, i've been searching for a little bit now and i can't make it work on android 4.

THANKS!

Comment: assuming that you're getting `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` ... you shouldn't do internet operation on main thread ... use Threads (fx.: AsyncTask)

Comment: As a alternative to use AsyncTask, check out the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8706464/defaulthttpclient-to-androidhttpclient/8706961#8706961) to see if it helps.

Comment: @yorkw That answer is really really really bad practice, it would be 100% better to do it in an Async task.

Comment: @SmartLemon, exactly, as I mentioned in my answer in the end. Also note that the really really bad practice you talking about is existed and allowed for long time until API level 11.

Answer (score 7):

You need to put this in an Async task, it will not run in the main thread in 3.0 >

use this:

```
public class PostTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Boolean> {

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            boolean result = false;

            //All your code goes in here 

            //If you want to do something on the UI use progress update

            publishProgress("progress");
            return result;
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 1; i < progress.length; i++) {
                    str.append(progress[i] + " ");
                }

        }
    }
```

You need a reference to it outside the async task

```
PostTask posttask;
```

then you need to start it

```
posttask = new PostTask();
posttask.execute();
```

I had the exact same problem a couple of days ago, goodluck

Answer (score 1):

With Android 4.0 you cant use http connection without using a Thread (with a runnable, asyinctask ... )

**The best you can do is implements a Thread** but if you cant do it you cant delete in the android manifest android:targetVersion="14".

If you need some elements of the version 14/higher  like Holo theme or something you can configure in

Right clink in the project --> Propierties --> Android --> Project Built Target = 14 or that you want

Comment: This wouldn't be a very good idea, the reason they have done this is that when you do any networking requests it can block the main UI thread which can cause a FC, we dont want that happening so we need to do it in a thread, they let it slide because it didn't seem like developers would do that I think.

Comment: I know but i mark the best to do is implement a thread but there are some times that is imposible to do it for some reason and this is a momentary solution. The best, i repit, is implement a AsyncTask to make HTTP petitions Allways how you say. I vote up you answer but i think is good put thit "bad" solution too.

Comment: @Aracem you can also disable strict mode .... but is really, really, really, ..., really bad practice

Comment: I know @Selvin but, how i say before, perhaps help somebody in some situation. Repit, the best is SmartLemon solution!