# HTTP Request Android Dev

Tags: android, httprequest, http-get

I'm trying to request for HTTP but it's dying on me on

> HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

Below is my code...

```
public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {
    // HTTP Request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        System.out.println("CRAZY1");
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        System.out.println("CRAZY2");
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        System.out.println("CRAZY3");

        System.out.println("CRAZY4");
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        System.out.println("CRAZY5");
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        System.out.println("CRAZY6");
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

It's telling me thread is exiting with uncaught exception. I do have permissions enabled in the manifest. What could be the problem?

Comment: The answer is probably here:  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8706464/defaulthttpclient-to-androidhttpclient][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8706464/defaulthttpclient-to-androidhttpclient

Comment: I don't believe that's the case, because my build target is for 2.2 supporting min android version 2.2

Comment: did you try to make a request to onCreate method?

Comment: Actually the problem was solved from one of the links i had to do a supresslint however but it works now

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your URL includes http:// or else the constructor of HttpGet will throw a IllegalArgumentException.