# Android: Creating and Sending an XML SOAP Request Programmatically

Tags: android, xml, soap, wsdl

Hi and thanks in advance. I found this tutorial and I'm trying to emulate it: http://lalit3686.blogspot.com/2012/06/calling-soap-webservice-using-httppost.html. In my iOS app I'm able to create a string with xml properties, send it as a SOAP request, and get an xml response in string form. I'm trying to do the same thing with my android app.

Unfortunately something isn't working. I've attached relevant code.

```
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder ();
    stringBuilder.append(String.format("<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"\n" +
            "xmlns:csr=\"http://www.mywebsite.net/\">\n" +
            "<soapenv:Header/>\n" +
            "<soapenv:Body>\n" +
            "<csr:www.mywebsite.net><![CDATA[\n" +
            "<www.mywebsite.net>\n" +
            "<Request>\n" +
            "<user>%s</user>\n" +
            "<password>%s</password>\n" +
            "<Function>requestdata</Function>\n" +
            "<FromDate>2013-01-01</FromDate>\n" +
            "<ToDate>2014-01-01</ToDate>\n" +
            "</Request>\n" +
            "</www.mywebsite.net>\n" +
            "]]></csr:www.mywebsite.net>\n" +
            "</soapenv:Body>\n" +
            "</soapenv:Envelope>\n", username, password));

    String xml = stringBuilder.toString();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://www.mywebsite.net/");
    StringEntity entity;
    String response_string = null;

    try {

        entity = new StringEntity(xml, HTTP.UTF_8);
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type","text/xml;charset=UTF-8");
        httpPost.setEntity(entity);
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
        response_string = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        Log.d("request", response_string);
        prefs.edit().putString("response", response_string).commit();

    } 

    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Edit: problem fixed. I was getting the error:

```
android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099).
```

The code above works - just make sure to include this code in your onCreate() method.

```
 if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
  StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
  StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
 }
```

This allows you to use the main thread for SOAP requests/responses.

Comment: please refer this site http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/

Comment: do you get any errors ??

Comment: atrix- android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was getting the error:

android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099).

I googled this error and came upon this link: [DefaultHttpClient to AndroidHttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8706464/defaulthttpclient-to-androidhttpclient) - which suggested I include the following code in my onCreate method.

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
  StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
  StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
}
```

Now its working. In fact, Android does not let network operations be performed on the main thread any longer.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you run network operation on UI thread which violates Strict Mode. Use AsyncTask for background operation.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v9EowBVgwSo. The video has a tutorial of how to go about sending a soap webservice request in android.

http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/using-ksoap2-android-and-parsing-output-data. The link here has an example with explanation. Go through the links and modify your code accordingly.

Sending request in xml form. I had a similar requirement and i used the below format to sent a soap reuest in xml form. Modify the below according to your needs. I

```
PropertyInfo loginreq = new PropertyInfo();
loginreq.name="LoginReq";
loginreq.type=String.class;
loginreq.setValue("<LoginReq>" 
     +"<nickName>"+name+"</nickName>" 
     +"<password>"+pass+"</password>" 
     +"<IMEI>"+mImei+"</IMEI>" 
     +"<location>" 
     +"<latitude>"+lati+"</latitude>"
         +"<longitude>"+longi+"</longitude>"
     +"</location>" 
     +"</LoginReq>");
request.addProperty(loginreq);
```

[Android, sending XML via HTTP POST (SOAP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559948/android-sending-xml-via-http-post-soap). Have a look at the accepeted answer in the link.

Edit

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/. Have a look at the heading Creating XML.

Comment: the line response.put("HTTPStatus",httpResponse.getStatusLine().toString()); gives me an error... i'm tinkering with it at the moment.

Comment: try the above code by adding property to the request.http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html#ObjectCreation. You have too many strings in your code. have a look at the link under the heading Avoid Creating Unnecessary Objects.

Comment: is your response also in xml format. What is the error that your getting??

Comment: i'm expecting a response in xml format - but i was planning on parsing through it as a string as i did in my ios app

Comment: so u r getting response?? u need to parse that response now??

Comment: yeah - i think i'll design my own code to parse the response though - thanks for the suggestions