# Android doesn't connect to MS SQL database, but Java console does...?

Tags: java, android, sql, sql-server

I am developping an Android app with a sql server, when we try to get records out of the database, we can view them in the java console.

However, when we test our app on Android, the connection is null and we do not see any records?

We're using JTDS 1.2.5 to connect with the database. On Android we receive a SQL-exception when the app attemps a 'getConnection()'

[image]

[image]

Comment: Posting the exception will help. Is your android device able to resolve the hostname of the database ? You cannot use `localhost` on the device, just in case your connect string uses that.

Comment: The server is on a VPN network wich the device has a vpn connection to..

Stack trace:

see edit top post

Comment: Show stackTrace and you approrach.. Only then anybody can suggest you something

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8706464/defaulthttpclient-to-androidhttpclient

This solved my question :D

Answer (score -1):

Could you please write the stack trace?
It could be very useful in order to solve the problem.

Without seeying it I can suppose that maybe you've incorrectly loaded the SQL JDBC driver and for this reason the program is unable to load the class.

Comment: this is not an answer, please use comments for clarifications

Comment: My reputation doesn't grant to me to add comment.

Comment: oh did not know that, +1 to make it even :)

Comment: @AlessandroSuglia  .. dont worry i upvoted ur answer :) .. I understand your problem ;)

Comment: Don't worry about that.
Maybe do you have to add the permission to use the network?
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE

See here how to add a permission on the android manifest: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element.html