# Creating new socket returns a null socket

Tags: android

I have been trying to initiate a socket connection within my application like this:

```
Socket socket =null;
try{
socket = new Socket("192.168.43.206",10000);
} catch(IOException e){
    Log.d("Socket ",e.getLocalizedMessage());
}
```

I have a TCP server running on my PC which is connected to the same router as the phone on which i am debugging. But when I debug and check the object socket it contains null and yet there were no exceptions caught. What am i doing
wrong?

Comment: Is there a firewall running on your machine ? If yes , disable it for some time and check

Comment: @Kulkarni I disabled the firewall

Answer (score 2):

(Would like to paste it as a comment, but have too little reputation)

Try catching the other exceptions and look if they are thrown:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html

If you use linux, you can check if you can connect to that TCP connection (from PC) using netcat:
    [my]$ nc 192.168.43.206 10000

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have added internet permission in manifest. i.e.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

See [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6778103/a-simple-socket-app-in-android-needs-some-special-permissions-to-connect-through)