# How to connect to a server using Socket in Android

Tags: java, android, sockets

I want my Android phone to connect to my other server.  I’m not sure how do I send request to the server receive the response.

Here is my code

```
try
{
Socket connfd = new Socket("192.168.1.100", 5000 );
InputStream in = connfd.getInputStream();
OutputStream out = connfd.getOutputStream();
BufferedReader con = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
}catch(IOException e1){
    e1.printStackTrace();

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7384678/how-to-create-socket-connection-in-android

Comment: [Here](http://myandroidsolutions.blogspot.ro/2013/03/android-tcp-connection-enhanced.html) you can find a sample.
I hope it helps :)