# How do i translate this code into a Android app code

Tags: android, python, sockets

Its just a simple python client to interact with a python server, i am trying now to implement the following code on Android app but i am new to Android, any help?

```
import socket
import json

host='127.0.0.1'
port=9090
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect((host,port))


while True:
   data = "Message to send"
   sock.send(data)
   response = json.loads(sock.recv(1024))
   print response
   sock.close()
   quit()
```

I have this for now, since its running on a Fragment i had to create a new thread since connections should not be done on UI Thread.

```
class ClientThread implements Runnable {

@Override
 public void run() {
    final String msg = "message to send";
    Log.d(msg, "sending this");
    try {
        String msg_received = null;
        System.out.println("TRYING TO CONNECT");

        InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(HOST);

        Socket socket = new Socket(HOST, PORT);

        System.out.println("CONNECTED");

        System.out.println(socket.getLocalAddress());
        OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();

        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(out);
        output.println(msg);
        output.flush();

        // Get data sent through socket
        DataInputStream DIS = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());


        // read data that got sent
        msg_received = DIS.readUTF();

        System.out.println("Message from server" + msg_received);

        socket.close();


            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Did not receive string");
            }




}

}
```

Nothing is being printed after

```
Socket socket = new Socket(HOST, PORT);
```

Where did i got this wrong?

Comment: Go to https://developer.android.com/ and learn Android.

Comment: Sorry, this isn't Google Translate for code. Learn some Java first

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101754/is-there-a-way-to-run-python-on-android?rq=1

Comment: I dont want a integral translation, only some ideas of how to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Socket` requires the app to have the `INTERNET` permission.  Try adding this to your `manifest.xml`:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Can also take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7384678/how-to-create-socket-connection-in-android) for more details.