# readLine of socket input stream causes hang in socket

Tags: java, android, sockets

hi I have an application that sends text to a device and the device shows it on a display. for transferring data I'm using socket in a `AsyncTask` class

```
            try {
                Socket socket = new Socket(DISPLAY_IP, DISPLAY_PORT);
                OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
                PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(out);
                output.println(params[0]);
                output.flush();
                socket.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

the problem is I can't read response from socket after sending data. when I'm getting input stream from socket and reading line I'm not getting anything and the device is not showing the sent data from me till I close the application so I think the socket is blocking when I'm doing that

```
           try {
                Socket socket = new Socket(DISPLAY_IP, DISPLAY_PORT);
                OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
                PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(out);
                output.println(params[0]);
                output.flush();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                String response = bufferedReader.readLine();
                socket.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

how can I send data and read response from socket?

Comment: Not really sure what the problem is, but readLine() is *supposed* to hang - it will until a line is in fact sent by the other end (or until the connection times out or gets broken). I'd recommend trying to send the same message using netcat and seeing if you're getting a response - it might be a problem with the server, not the client.

Comment: the server is sending me `OK` after received data I just sent so what should I do? @SirGregg

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to communicate with two (client) `Socket`s. For communication you must implement on one side a (client) `java.net.Socket` and on the other a **`java.net.ServerSocket`**.

You may read further [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7384678/how-to-create-socket-connection-in-android).

Comment: let me try it @PeterMmm

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve?
When using InputStream it will get data that came from other side, not the data that you just sent.
And as SirGregg said `readLine` will hang until the whole line is received.

Comment: I need to know the server received my data so it sent me back a `OK` and I need to read it

Comment: @Amir_P Probably server does not sent \n, so line is not ended. readLine will wait end-of-line character