# Android: have app send request to another app over network (on other phone)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, network-programming

I have two apps: "app" and "receiver", the latter of which also runs as a  service on the phone. These are designed to be run on two separate phones - only one receiver will ever exist, which will be on my phone.

I'll try to make the problem as simple as I can: from the app, I'd like to be able to press a button saying 'hello', which would then load up an activity on the receiver's phone (from the service) also saying 'hello'. Pretty much I just don't know how to get the two devices to talk to each other. This will only be used over the same Wi-Fi connection. Would a broadcast be a suitable way to do this?

I've just started Android development a few days ago so I'm not sure how to do it - it's probably simple - and any help will be massively appreciated!

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Would a broadcast be a suitable way to do this?

No. Broadcasts can be used for inter-app communication, not inter-device communication.

Instead, devices on the same LAN can adress each other using their local IPs (usually 192.168.x.x).

One option would be to open a socket connection,  see [how to create Socket connection in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7384678/how-to-create-socket-connection-in-android)

Comment: Thank you - perfect and descriptive answer! I'll have a look into it.