# App not showing network activity in Android Studio's Profiler

Tags: android, sockets, httpurlconnection

I am trying to analyze my app's network activity such as number of connections and total size of response and request per connection.
However, it won't register in my Profiler's Network section.

I am using Java sockets as explained in [how to create Socket connection in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7384678/how-to-create-socket-connection-in-android).

How do you show it in the tool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, the Android Studio's (Network) Profiler only captures connections made thru `HttpURLConnection` and `OkHttp` classes. This won't work if you are using `Socket` from the Java API.

Source: https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/network-profiler