# How can i send messages fron android stuido app to python server?

Tags: android, python, sockets, server

So I need to send messages from android stuio application to python. I look all over the web and all i found is this n' its not working :(

if you can please look at my code and explain me how to fix it, I will be glad!!!! (the server has sql in it so im sorry for all the other mess about it

the server side (python):

```
import sqlite3
import socket
import sys

HOST = '0.0.0.0'
PORT = 5000

conn = sqlite3.connect('try.db')
c = conn.cursor()

try:
    c.execute('''CREATE TABLE highScores
         (name text, score real)''')
print("table build in success")
#check if table alreay exist in this file
#if not exist, it will build one.
except:
    print("table exist")

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
# create the socket
print ('socket created')

try:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
except socket.error as err:
    print("bind failed")
    #close if bund failed
    sys.exit()
print ('Socket Bind Success!')
# start listen
s.listen(1)
print ('Socket is now listening')

while 1:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print ('Connect with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1]))
    #connect with client
    buf = conn.recv(64)
    print (buf)
    playerName, playerScore ='', ''
    for i in buf:
         if i in '0123456789':
        playerScore += i
    else:
        playerName += i
    finalScore = int(playerScore)
    c.execute("INSERT INTO highScores (name, score) VALUES ('{}', {})".format(playerName, finalScore))
    # add player data to table, and save the table
    conn.commit()
    #recive from client message and print it
    for row in c.execute('SELECT * FROM highScores ORDER BY score'):
        print(row)
        # print the table by order: first place will print first, last place will print last
s.close()
#close the socket


conn.commit()
#save the table again (just for sure) and close it
conn.close()
```

the android side:

the activity:

```
package com.example.appproj;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class lastScreen extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    TextView tvWon;
    Button btn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_last_screen);
        tvWon = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvWon);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.lastbtn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
        etScore = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etScore);
        etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etScore);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (help.won) {
            tvWon.setText("you won");
            new MessageSender().execute(etName.getText().toString() +etScore.getText().toString());
        }
       else {
        tvWon.setText("you lose");
        }
    }
}
```

MessageSender:

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

public class MessageSender extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    private Exception exception;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            try {
                Socket socket = new Socket(ip, 5000);
                PrintWriter outToServer = new PrintWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(
                            socket.getOutputStream()));
                outToServer.print(params[0]);
                outToServer.flush();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            this.exception = e;
            return null;
        }
        return  null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Easier solution would be to use something like `flask` as your server in python, and use `okhttp` or `retrofit` to connect (make API calls) to your server.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7384678/how-to-create-socket-connection-in-android seems similar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to create Socket connection in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7384678/how-to-create-socket-connection-in-android)

Comment: You have used `conn` for two unrelated things in your python server code. Why do I have the feeling you haven't posted the actual code?