# Is it possible to open a server network socket from an android app without the root permission?

Tags: android, sockets, networking, permissions

I want to create a communication between two Android devices.

One is a server and another is a client.

Is it possible to open a server network socket from an android app without the root permission?

Comment: What have you tried? What is the error message? See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074808/java-socket-ioexception-permission-denied

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### YES

You have to add  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`
permission in your Application's `Manifest` file

Comment: shortest answer ever !