# my android app keeps closing when i press a button

Tags: android, sockets

i am making a android app that connects to my chat server.  When I start the app and press the Join button it stops I don't know what the problem is.  If you can help me thank you in advance.

```
package com.example.marcus.chatclient1;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;

public class chat extends AppCompatActivity {
public Socket s;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);

    final Button join = (Button)findViewById(R.id.joinButton);
    join.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText nameText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
            String name = nameText.getText().toString();
            join.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            nameText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            TextView errorT = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.errorText);
            try {
                s = new Socket("192.168.0.15", 55555);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Post the stacktrace of the exception.

Comment: i added e.printStackTrace(); but it doesn't show an exception it just says "Unfortunately, ChatClient1 has stopped"

Comment: You catch the IOException, so it won't crash there. You probably have a NullPointerException somewhere, check the logs and then copy it here.

Comment: i am catching the IOException but it still just crashes and doesn't says  "Unfortunately, ChatClient1 has stopped" it doesn't show an error

Comment: i updated the code and took out the ObjectOutputStream and i am just trying to connect but it still doesn't work.

Comment: You wouldn't happen to do [network IO on the UI thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception), right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically there are answers here

- [The code Socket clientSocket = new Socket(); crashes in android app. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29992292/the-code-socket-clientsocket-new-socket-crashes-in-android-app-why)
- https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/274551/%D0%9A%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-android-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80-java-app

You problem it that you are trying to create socket on a main thread.