# Android 6 (23) - no permission requested

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions, permission-denied

I stucked on new permission model in the Android 6.

I defined following permissions in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

<application...
```

But if i launched the app in the emulator and opened the app detail i saw the following :

[image]

It says that app does not require any permission.

How can i solve it please?

Many thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 6):

> It says that app does not require any permission.

That is correct. That portion of your app's page lists `dangerous` permissions. None of yours have a `protectionLevel` of `dangerous`.

> How can i solve it please?

There is nothing wrong, and so there is nothing to solve.

Answer (score 4):

Until Android 6.0, There are some permissions that will be automatically granted at install time and will not be able to revoke. We call it Normal Permission (**PROTECTION_NORMAL**). Here is the full list of them:

```
android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS
android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY
android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE
android.permission.ACCESS_WIMAX_STATE
android.permission.BLUETOOTH
android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN
android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY
android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE
android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE
android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE
android.permission.CHANGE_WIMAX_STATE
android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD
android.permission.EXPAND_STATUS_BAR
android.permission.FLASHLIGHT
android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS
android.permission.GET_PACKAGE_SIZE
android.permission.INTERNET
android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES
android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS
android.permission.NFC
android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS
android.permission.READ_SYNC_STATS
android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED
android.permission.REORDER_TASKS
android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES
android.permission.SET_TIME_ZONE
android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER
android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER_HINTS
android.permission.SUBSCRIBED_FEEDS_READ
android.permission.TRANSMIT_IR
android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT
android.permission.VIBRATE
android.permission.WAKE_LOCK
android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS
com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM
com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT
com.android.launcher.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT
```

Just simply declare those permissions in AndroidManifest.xml and it will work just fine. No need to check for the permission listed above since it couldn't be revoked.

Comment: Thanks, upvoted. Also, added a comparison between old and new here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55118424/984471

Answer (score 3):

as @Saini said, Beginning in Android 6.0 (API level 23), users grant permissions to apps while the app is running, not when they install the app.
But if you choose **targetSdkVersion** lower than 23, your application will be treated like before and will ask user to grant permission to the app when they want to install application. you could read more from [here](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to https://stackoverflow.com/a/42697645/984471

Here is the protection_normal permissions link:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview#normal_permissions

And the comparison between old and new, normals

[image: protection_normal permissions]

Answer (score 2):

Beginning in Android 6.0 (API level 23), users grant permissions to apps while the app is running, not when they install the app. This approach streamlines the app install process, since the user does not need to grant permissions when they install or update the app. It also gives the user more control over the app's functionality; for example, a user could choose to give a camera app access to the camera but not to the device location. The user can revoke the permissions at any time, by going to the app's Settings screen.

For more info: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/declaring.html

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/best-practices.html

```
// Here, thisActivity is the current activity
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
                Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    // Should we show an explanation?
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
            Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)) {

        // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
        // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
        // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

    } else {

        // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);

        // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
        // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
        // result of the request.
    }
}
```